# Is Yii2 compatible with PHP 7?

Tags: yii2, php-7

Since PHP 7 got released and I'm planing to start a new project that uses Yii2. My question is, it is safe to use PHP 7 with Yii2?

Comment: On http://www.yiiframework.com/news/92/php-7-released/ : "Yii 2.0 is compatible with PHP 7 and should run on it without any issues."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, Yii2 is compatible with PHP 7. Some FAQ's of that:

1) [Yii2 and PHP 7](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63662-yii2-and-php-7/)
2) [Yii Feed](http://yiifeed.com/)
3) [PHP 7 Released](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/92/php-7-released/)
4) [Yii2 PHP 7 Performance](https://caleblloyd.com/software/yii2-php-7-performance/)
5) [PHP-7-released-does-yii2-need-changes?](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/68806-php-7-released-does-yii2-need-changes/)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for the most part there should be no issues using Yii2 with PHP7. Please see the following on the forum:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63662-yii2-and-php-7/

I also found the following on github:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8975

Both of these suggest that if there are any issues you should report them to the Yii Team but as far as they are concerned there should be little to no issue. The Yii team are quick to fix these things and obviously the adoption of version 7 will only increase so it is in their best interest to move with the times.

Answer (score 1):

I run my application under php 7 and until now, i have not any problem.

[image]